# What's the easiest way to update an entry from the front end as a guest user and only post the data that needs to be updated?

Tags: plugin-development, entries, entrymodel, guest-entries, plugin-guestentries

I'm creating a multi-page form on the front end of a site where different data is added to the entry depending on the page they are on. Originally I was going to create the entries using P&T's guest entries, but that doesn't allow the user to edit an entry once it's submitted, so I created a plugin based on [this question](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/583/how-do-i-save-a-matrix-field-with-an-asset-block-programmatically) to handle saving the entry as a user with sufficient privileges.

The problem I'm having is that once a user submits new data from the front-end that doesn't include the data already saved to the entry, the previously saved information is erased. I am hoping to avoid including the existing data on each submission to keep things easy.

Is there a way to use something similar `$entry->setContentFromPost('fields');` while updating existing entries?

**Controller code:**

```
class Plugin_Controller extends BaseController
{
    /**
     * @var Allows anonymous access to this controller's actions.
     * @access protected
     */
    protected $allowAnonymous = true;

    public function actionSaveEntry()
    {       
        $this->requirePostRequest();

        $entryId = craft()->userSession->getState('entryId');

        $entry = craft()->entries->getEntryById($entryId);

        if (!$entry)
        {
            // Fields
            $entry = new EntryModel();
            $entry->sectionId  = 1;
            $entry->locale     = 'en_us';
            $entry->postDate   = date('Y-m-d');
            $entry->authorId   = 1;
        }

        // Tell our content model where to look for custom fields
        $entry->setContentFromPost('fields');

        // Content
        $entry->getContent()->title = "Title";

        // Save the entry content
        craft()->entries->saveEntry($entry);

        $this->redirectToPostedUrl();

    }

}
```

**Front-end Form**

```
<form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    {{ getCsrfInput() }}
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="plugin/saveEntry">
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="/builder?step={{ nextStep }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="title" value="{{ title }}" />
    <input type="hidden" name="sectionId" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="enabled" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="fields[matrix][new1][type]" value="service">
    <input type="hidden" name="fields[matrix][new1][enabled]" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="fields[matrix][new1][fields][entry]" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="fields[matrix][new1][fields][entry][]" value="{{ entry.id }}">
    <button>Update</button>
</form>
```

Any thoughts on how I could accomplish this with the least amount of non-core code possible?

Comment: Have you thought about getting the entry using it's ID (within your plugin) then replacing the data that your form has submitted before re-saving it?